# Nodejs Websocket on GAE

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket

I want to deploy Nodejs websocket application on Google App Engine (GAE), I have tried for the past 3 days with no success

I keep getting the error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

this is my app.js file in Nodejs

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 65080 }),
    CLIENTS = [];

    console.log('WS listening on port 65080');
// on new connection    
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

    console.log('incoming connection ....');
    ws.id = uuid.v4();
    CLIENTS.push(ws);
    ws.send('{"type":"uuid","value":"' + ws.id + '"}');
});
```

I have opened firewall port successfully , like this

[image]

and this is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
api_version: 1
service: websockets

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  forwarded_ports:
  - 65080
  session_affinity: true
  instance_tag: websocket
```

any advice is appreciated..

Comment: I suggest to explicitly write 65080/tcp in the yaml file. Have You opened this port in Google Firewall?

Comment: same error when I changed the app.yaml to 65080/tcp... I cant open the websocket

Comment: I have opened the port also in the firwall

Comment: See this comment on Google public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348#comment212 it seems Websockets aren't available for GOOGLE APP ENGINE flexible yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348#comment212) on Google public issue tracker:

[image]

It seems Web-sockets aren't available for GOOGLE APP ENGINE flexible yet. I recommend you to star the issue so you can follow the updates.